# Is there a way to get the paragraph number using office word js api from the range object or the paragraph itself?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

Can someone please let me know if there is any way that I could retrieve the paragraph number from a paragraph or the range object using office word js api? Working on implementing selections based on data that I get from a back end service, which provides both paragraph numbers and offsets. But, the paragraph numbers seem to be off by the cumulative number of table rows found in the document.

Comment: There is no such API available. You can post or vote for an existing feature request on [Tech Community](https://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions) where they are considered when the Office dev team go through the planning process.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no office js api to retrieve the paragraph number from a paragraph or the range object.
But I think you can get all of the paragraphs and iterate everyone to set the index number to every paragraph. Thus, you could calculate any paragraph number.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That's the current approach that I'm taking and I see this is not ideal when iterating through a 100+ page document with 10000 paragraphs. Performance impact is significant.

Comment: I think this could be a new feature request. For new feature request, we would like to suggest you go to https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform and see if your question has already been asked or ask a new question. Feature requests on it are considered when we go through our planning process.  Thanks again for reaching us.

Answer (score 1):

I’m currently gathering all the paragraph objects up front and adding ranges to each one. It does not take long, even with hundreds of pages. To avoid the table cells (each of which is also a paragraph), there is a property that indicates which paragraphs are in tables.